# Querying Pandas DataFrame with column name that contains a space or using the drop method with a column name that contains a space

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to use `pandas` to drop rows based on the column name (contains a space) and the cell value. I have tried various ways to achieve this (drop and query methods) but it seems I'm failing due to the space in the name. Is there a way to query the data using the name that has a space in it or do I need to clean all spaces first?

**data in form of a csv file**

```
Date,"price","Sale Item"
2012-06-11,1600.20,item1
2012-06-12,1610.02,item2
2012-06-13,1618.07,item3
2012-06-14,1624.40,item4
2012-06-15,1626.15,item5
2012-06-16,1626.15,item6
2012-06-17,1626.15,item7
```

**Attempt Examples**

```
df.drop(['Sale Item'] != 'Item1')
df.drop('Sale Item' != 'Item1')
df.drop("'Sale Item'] != 'Item1'")

df.query('Sale Item' != 'Item1')
df.query(['Sale Item'] != 'Item1')
df.query("'Sale Item'] != 'Item1'")
```

**Error received in most cases**

```
ImportError: 'numexpr' not found. Cannot use engine='numexpr' for query/eval if 'numexpr' is not installed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly your issue, maybe you can just apply a filter like:

```
df = df[df['Sale Item'] != 'item1']
```

which returns:

```
         Date    price Sale Item
1  2012-06-12  1610.02     item2
2  2012-06-13  1618.07     item3
3  2012-06-14  1624.40     item4
4  2012-06-15  1626.15     item5
5  2012-06-16  1626.15     item6
6  2012-06-17  1626.15     item7
```

Comment: That will work, if I dont get an answer using the drop method will happily accept this as a work around. Thank you Fabio

Comment: @iNoob Why do you need a method using `drop` ?

Comment: Because id prefer it, if it exists

Comment: in terms of performance, which is quicker? `df.quer()` or `df[df[] ]` ?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) -

> **DataFrame.drop(labels, axis=0, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')**
>
> Return new object with labels in requested axis removed

[`DataFrame.drop()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) takes the `index` of the rows to drop, not the condition. Hence you would most probably need something like -

```
df.drop(df.ix[df['Sale Item'] != 'item1'].index)
```

Please note, this drops the rows that meet the condition, so the result would be the rows that don't meet the condition, if you want the opposite you can use `~` operator before your condition to negate it.

But this seems a bit too much, it would be easier to just use Boolean indexing to get the rows you want (as indicated in the other answer) .

---

Demo -

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
         Date    price Sale Item
0  2012-06-11  1600.20     item1
1  2012-06-12  1610.02     item2
2  2012-06-13  1618.07     item3
3  2012-06-14  1624.40     item4
4  2012-06-15  1626.15     item5
5  2012-06-16  1626.15     item6
6  2012-06-17  1626.15     item7

In [21]: df.drop(df.ix[df['Sale Item'] != 'item1'].index)
Out[21]:
         Date   price Sale Item
0  2012-06-11  1600.2     item1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anand. Can you explain why the answer by Fabio is better than the drop method? As I understand it the drop method was developed for this exact purpose? Dont get me wrong you and Fabio are much more experienced than I am. I am only trying to learn from you and understand why you believe it is a better option.

Comment: To me the other method looks shorter. The only advantage I see for `drop` method is that it has an inplace argument which can be used to change the dataframe inplace.

Comment: Ok, I have now I have had time to use both and have actually found Fabio's answer to be more usable. I am now stuck with the predicament of accepting an answer. Yours answers my question directly but Fabio's I have found more usable.

Comment: Thank you Anand, you are a pillar to the community ;)